# Unexpected strcmp behaviour with strings containing backticks

Tags: php, string-comparison, strcmp, backticks

I'm facing a strange problem with the [strcmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) function.
I need to compare 2 strings containing the backtick character (`):

```
$result = strcmp('CREATE TABLE `postsTranslations` (', 'CREATE TABLE `posts` (');
```

I expected that the result of this comparison should be `>0` since `postsTranslations` is alphabetically after  `posts`. But the result is `-1`. If I remove the backticks, everything works as expected. Would it be possible to alphabetically compare these strings without removing backticks?

Comment: Check the ASCII table: space (0x20) < `T` (0x54) < `\`` (0x60). The sorting is correct according to `strcmp`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [strcasecmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) here. It does the binary safe case-insensitive string comparison.